# conflict google-analytics-data and protobuf

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, grpc-python

I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named proto" after install the google-analytics-data package in my grpcproject. This package conflicts with protobuf==3.17.0.

I have tried using different versions of google-analytics-data and protobuf, but the problem persists continues.